# Reversão de git pull

Tags: git

Fiz um Git Pull e sobrescreveu tudo que tinha no código existe.

Na minha empresa utilizávamos o SVN e lá eu realizava um update depois um commit e o sistema realizava sempre um merge de tudo, porém a empresa migrou tudo para git e já é a segunda vez que me acontece isso.

Realizei um git pull antes de commitar minhas mudanças, porém  o que ocorreu foi que ele não fez o merge das mudanças, o git pegou tudo que o outro dev.

Existe alguma forma de reverter para o estado anterior?

Comment: Ficaste com o pull a meio e com erros ou ficou limpo e apagou o que tinhas?

Comment: Apagou minhas alterações locais e substituiu para as em servidor, e como não fiz nenhum commit antes ele não volta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira mais moderna de fazer isso:

```
git merge --abort
```

E um jeito um pouco mais correto de fazer isso:

```
git reset --merge
```

As maneiras descritas antes da edição da reposta descartariam as acoes locais:

```
 git reset HEAD@{1}
```

---

[Resposta original aqui - SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223354/undo-git-pull-how-to-bring-repos-to-old-state)

Comment: Não seria caso de `git merge --abort`?

Comment: nunca usei, mas buscando vi que nas ultimas versoes do git esse comando pode ser usado. @Sergio